# Add value centerly aligned in a column in CSV generate rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to add a value in center of first row in csv using CSV.generate

Comment: Please provide the code you've written so far so we can help you debug it.

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: -headers = ['Category#']
=CSV.generate_line(headers).strip.html_safe

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible as CSV is just a comma separated file and does not contain any data about styling. Alternatively, you can add an empty column(s) (commas) to mimic this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange request since .CSV is not a presentation layer. Formatted values are not typically stored in .CSV but I suppose there's no reason they can't be.

The Ruby method `center` should help.

```
"hello".center(20) #=> "       hello        "
```

Then just put the centered value into you .CSV.